# auto login google docs

Tags: google-docs

Situation:
Users can access their google docs by an external link on a website. Now they first have to login to view their documents.

Problem:
I want that the users automaticly login on Google Docs

I've the username and password stored in a dabasase..

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to solve this. You could fake a login programmatically, but that would work only to fetch a document, not to really log in the client. Plus it's really not a good idea to have a database with peoples' Google logins lying around, especially seeing as the passwords have to be unencrypted.

I would leave it up to the user to store their Google password in the local browser.